# PHP Zend framework: how to kill a very annoying and useless error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using the Zend GData library to integrate Google Calendar in my PHP application.

I get tens of errors like this:

```
Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/Calendar/Content.php' for inclusion
```

but actually everything works awesomely (I am able to create/delete/update calendars and events)

I don't know exactly why I get that. Probably the Zend loader tries to load a file that doesn't exist (that is why the error) but, then, tries another location with success (that is why everything works).

By the way this is the bootstrap code I use for loading the Zend classes in my PHP script:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
```

What I want to achieve is to kill those error messages without killing other categories of relevant messages.
How would you achieve that?
I have tried to wrap everything in a `try{} catch{}` block but I still get those error messages.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Wouldn't just $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); be all you need?

Comment: Zend_Loader::loadClass is deprecated , as richard suggest use `Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();`

Comment: Thanks Richard. And what would I do after I get an instance of the autoloader?

Comment: I mean: how can I load the classes: Zend_Gdata, Zend_Gdata_AuthSub,Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin, Zend_Gdata_Calendar

Comment: getInstance() initialises the autoloader if it has not already been initialised. Once you've done that all classes should load automatically on demand, you don't need to do anything else. If you are still seeing errors, ensure you have Zend Framework on your include path (as in Richard Knop's answer).

Comment: Oh and try & catch catches exceptions, the errors you are seeing are PHP errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use just few classes from Zend Framework it is recommended to upload the whole framework to your server to avoid any issues. It doesn't matter because you can still use just certain ZF classes and you will at least be sure there are no dependencies missing:

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'));
set_include_path(BASE_PATH.'/path/to/folder/where/zend/framework/is/located');

require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$zendAutoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// that's all you need
// now you can use any class from the framework
```

Comment: As Richard notes, just take the whole library, even if you use only a part of it. The only downside is space, but space is cheap. The upside is that whatever dependencies may exist - some class you need throws a custom exception class or uses a class from another part of the framework - are all covered. If you are really determined to copy only the minimal set of files that you can, then you can ake a look at [Jani Hartikainen's Packageizer](https://github.com/jhartikainen/packageizer)

Answer (score 0):

[Use the autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html#zend.loader.autoloader.usage). Just set path to the Zend library using php's set_include_path(). And then use autoloader's getInstance() method to activate the autoloading. If you use other autoloaders, you can push them onto the stack (see manual).

Comment: Hi Tomas. I guess I can't use that as I don't use the whole Zend Framework but only the Google Data library.

Comment: If you only want bits of zend then have you thought of editing the calendar zend lib to remove the unused includes (that's if it will keep working). major hackery

Comment: The autoloader loads only the required classes. There is NO PROBLEM in that ;)